# Track Flash Player error from backend

Tags: html5-video, automated-tests, jwplayer, flash, jwplayer6

I have a few live streams that my video player (JWplayer) is used to play. I want a mechanism to automatically load a live stream to test if the live stream loads in JWplayer or not - this needs to happen backend on the server side - preferably a unix flavoured machine.

For example, the live stream URL may change or there may be a cross domain error. Ultimately, if this happens, I want to remove the live stream from my database automatically.

1. Is it possible to do this automatically? Note that an m3u8 URL may play in quicktime but not in Flash because of m3u8 errors.
2. I would like a similar tracking mechanism linked to a HTML 5 player (that supports live m3u8 streams) - say quicktime (or maybe ffplay?)

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The player itself doesn't really have any backend mechanisms for this, however, you could always use our JavaScript API for this, specifically onError(), to do something. It might be possible to call onError(), then do something on the server side, but the API is really only for frontend purposes. Reference - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference

Comment: Yes, that's simple enough to do. But for an error to be thrown, the web page needs to be programmatically loaded. How does one load a web page at a particular URL on an Amazon unix machine?

Comment: I am not sure if I follow what you are asking here. Do you have an example of an error being thrown from the player?